# Matching a complex expression in python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have to create a unique textual marker in my document using Python 2.7, with the following function:

```
def build_textual_marker(number, id):
    return "[xxxcixxx[[_'" + str(number) + "'] [_'" + id + "']]xxxcixxx]"
```

the output looks like this : `[xxxcixxx[[_'1'] [_'24']]xxxcixxx]`

And then I have to catch any occurrence of this expression in my document. I ended up to the following regular expression but it seems not working fine:

```
marker_regex = "\[xxxcixxx\[(\[_*?\])\s(\[_*?\])\]xxxcixxx\]"
```

I was wondering how should I write the correct regex in this case?

Comment: You missed the `.` - [`\[xxxcixxx\[(\[_.*?\])\s(\[_.*?\])\]xxxcixxx\]`](https://regex101.com/r/pU5kP3/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
\[xxxcixxx\[\[_'.*?'\] \[_'.*?'\]\]xxxcixxx\]
```

Demo: http://regexr.com/3d887

Answer (score 2):

Rather than the lazy star, you might as well get along with a digit class directly (the function `build_textual_marker` takes a `number` parameter, doesn't it?):

```
\[xxxcixxx\[(\[_'\d+'\])\s(\[_'\d+'\])\]xxxcixxx\]
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rE9lU5/1).